# Perl Mojolicious not running as a detached process on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'm not sure if this is an OS specific issue or not. How do you get Mojolicious  to detach and run in the background? I spent a lot of time writing this web app and now that I'm finished I can't get it to run in the background. What I'm I missing or not understanding about Mojolicious? -thanks

```
use strict;
use warnings;

BEGIN {
    push @ARGV, qw(
          daemon -m production  -l http://127.0.0.1:3000
    );
}

use Mojolicious::Commands; 
Mojolicious::Commands->start_app( MyApp => @ARGV);
```

Comment: Why not use [`daemon` command](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Command/daemon), eg. `./myapp.pl daemon ...`, or `$daemon->run(@ARGV)` ?  Also: what happens when you run it the way you show?

Comment: Right now I run it from the DOS prompt and it runs in the foreground and I see the output of the activity. My expectations would be that when I start it from the DOS prompt that it would detach and run in the background allowing me to close the DOS prompt. I'm using the start_app function because I'm running Mojolicious from a class as a full app not lite app.

Comment: How do you run it? Please show the command line. To deploy a Mojo app, Mojolicious brings its own server called Hypnotoad. It not only goes into the backend, it also handles all kinds of multi-process behaviour automatically for you. As an alternative, you can also use a Plack based deployment and pick any PSGI server you want, like Twiggy, Gazelle or Starman, combined with either `plackup` or `server_starter` from Server::Starter.

Comment: Hi simbabque, I run it like this. I cd to C:\MyApp and then type script\Myapp.pl

Comment: When I run hypnotoad script\Myapp.pl I get the following error - Hypnotoad does not support fork emulation. So is Hypnotoad not supported on Windows?

Comment: @user1128792 By default, you cannot use hypnotoad on Windows, but you can use [morbo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Server::Morbo).  According to the [Mojolicious Guides FAQ](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Mojolicious/lib/Mojolicious/Guides/FAQ.pod#How-well-is-Windows-supported-by-Mojolicious?), you can use hypnotoad on Windows if you have installed "Windows Subsystem for Linux".

Comment: @simbabque The modules that you mentioned (Twiggy, Gazelle, Starman) do not have any "Pass" values listed under mswin32 column in CPANTesters.  In answering zdim's question, the OP mentioned running the code from a DOS prompt, which indicates that the OP is using Windows.

Comment: @dasgar true. But I think there are some Plack servers that run on Windows. It's just that it's really not the typical use case.